# Flatten column containing array of JSON in Pandas

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas, postgresql

I have a table in postgresql - `a_table` - which 1 column - `previous_names` - stored as an array of json - `CREATE a_table (..., previous name JSON [], ...)`.

I use this code snippet to upload the table into a pandas df:

```
DBNAME = "dname"
USER = "uame"
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={} user={}".format(DBNAME, USER))
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SET search_path TO schema_name")
conn.commit()

sql = "select * from a_table"
data = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
```

When I download the csv and upload to a pandas df the column in question contains an array of jsons (with varying length):

so a certain record would be:

```
[
 {
  "effective_from": "2006-08-02",
  "ceased_on": "2006-08-16",
  "name": "SUPERSTAY LIMITED"
 }
]
```

and another would be:

```
[
  {
    "effective_from": "2006-09-19",
    "ceased_on": "2012-01-31",
    "name": "MCM SYSTEMS (PIB) LIMITED"
  },
  {
    "ceased_on": "2006-09-19",
    "effective_from": "2006-07-24",
    "name": "MCM SYSTEMS (FDT) LIMITED"
  }
]
```

The `key:value` pairs in this column are not always the same number - and the record could also be an `NaN`.

What is the best way to flatten this column in Pandas?

I tried this but it didn't work:

`json_normalize(data=data[data.previous_company_names != None])`

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`

Ideally - I'd be able to have a df with that column flattened

before

```
col_id | col_name   | previous_names
-------+------------+-----------------
1      | 'Corp.'    | [{"effective_from": "2006-08-02","ceased_on": "2006-08-16","name": "SUPERSTAY LIMITED"}]
2      | 'Company'  | [{"effective_from": "2006-09-19","ceased_on": "2012-01-31","name": "MCM SYSTEMS (PIB) LIMITED"}, {"ceased_on": "2006-09-19","effective_from": "2006-07-24","name": "MCM SYSTEMS (FDT) LIMITED"}]
3      | 'Entr'     | None
```

after

```
col_1 | col_2      | effective_from   |  ceased_on   | name 
------+------------+------------------+--------------+------------------------------
1     | 'Corp.'    | '2006-08-02'     | '2006-08-16' | 'SUPERSTAY LIMITED'
2     | 'Company'  | '2006-09-19'     | '2006-09-19' | 'MCM SYSTEMS (PIB) LIMITED'
2     | 'Company'  | '2006-07-24'     | '2006-09-19' | 'MCM SYSTEMS (FDT) LIMITED'
3     | 'Entr'     | None             | None         | None
```

Maybe this is too complicated for Pandas and should be done in postgresql?

Comment: An array of JSON should initiate with brackets: `[`? I don't think that's a valid json tbh.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DF like the one you gave as an example:

```
dd = [
    {
        'col_id': 0,
        'col_name': 'Corp.',
        'previous_names': [
            {
                "effective_from": "2006-08-02",
                "ceased_on": "2006-08-16",
                "name": "SUPERSTAY LIMITED"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'col_id': 1,
        'col_name': 'Company',
        'previous_names': [
            {
                "effective_from": "2006-09-19",
                "ceased_on": "2012-01-31",
                "name": "MCM SYSTEMS (PIB) LIMITED"
            },
            {
                "ceased_on": "2006-09-19",
                "effective_from": "2006-07-24",
                "name": "MCM SYSTEMS (FDT) LIMITED"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'col_id': 2,
        'col_name': 'Entr',
        'previous_names': None
    }
]
ddf = pd.DataFrame(dd)
```

You can use [`iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
col_name, col_id, effective_from, ceased_on, name = [], [], [], [], []
for i in ddf.iterrows():
    if i[1].previous_names:
        for x in i[1].previous_names:
            col_id.append(i[1]['col_id'])
            col_name.append(i[1]['col_name'])
            effective_from.append(x['effective_from'])
            ceased_on.append(x['ceased_on'])
            name.append(x['name'])
    else:
        col_id.append(i[1]['col_id'])
        col_name.append(i[1]['col_name'])
        effective_from.append(np.nan)
        ceased_on.append(np.nan)
        name.append(np.nan)

pd.DataFrame({'col_id': col_id, 'col_name': col_name, 'effective_from': effective_from, 'ceased_on': ceased_on, 'name': name })
```

And get what you are after:

```
    col_id  col_name    effective_from  ceased_on   name
0   0          Corp.    2006-08-02     2006-08-16   SUPERSTAY LIMITED
1   1          Company  2006-09-19     2012-01-31   MCM SYSTEMS (PIB) LIMITED
2   1          Company  2006-07-24     2006-09-19   MCM SYSTEMS (FDT) LIMITED
3   2          Entr     NaN            NaN          NaN
```